# Scroll to bottom of div after AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am working on a messaging app and I am importing the conversation into the page with AJAX, so I am trying to find a way to have the div scrolled to the very bottom when the page loads. It is important that the div is **only** scrolled to the bottom on the first load, **it should not** scroll to the bottom on the refresh timer.

I am trying to use `$("#convo").scrollTop($("#convo").height());` but this does not work, and I do not see any error codes.

How can I accomplish this?

```js
  $(document).ready(function(){
   $("#convo").load("convo.php?DM=" + ID);
   $("#convo").scrollTop($("#convo").height());
      setInterval(function() {
          $("#convo").load("convo.php?DM=" + ID);
      }, 5000);
  });

  $(document).ready(function(){
   $("#sidebar").load("sidebar.php");
      setInterval(function() {
          $("#sidebar").load("sidebar.php");
      }, 5000);
  });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../resources/style.css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    
    <div id='convo'></div>
    
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try putting the measurement of the height in the `load` callback function. Looks like it's simply not populated with the content yet.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `$("#convo").scrollTop($("#convo")[0].scrollHeight())`

Comment: I tried this and did not have success. The post you sent is for an SQL query :)

Comment: Sorry my bad. Removed the incorrect link.

Comment: I have tried this and did not have success. There are no errors. Any suggestions?